# Jquery / Ajax - How to determine which form to .serialize if all forms have same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, javascriptserializer

On my mainPage.html, I dynamically created multiple forms each with different values in their input tag.. this is my mainPage.html:

```
<form class='voteForm' method="post" action="/post/likePost/">
    <button class="voteButton" type="submit">
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" name="postID" value="1" />
</form>

<form class='voteForm' method="post" action="/post/likePost/">
    <button class="voteButton" type="submit">
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" name="postID" value="2" />
</form>

<form class='voteForm' method="post" action="/post/likePost/">
    <button class="voteButton" type="submit">
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" name="postID" value="3" />
</form>
```

As you can see, all three forms are similar, just their value is different. Now, this is my JS function

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('.voteForm').click( function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert($('.voteForm').serialize());
});
</script>
```

The problem is, whenever I click on any of the forms, it keeps automatically assuming that the form clicked is the last form which has a value of '3' in input, so it keeps altering the number 3 regardless of which form I click. I'm assuming this is because I did

```
$('.voteForm').click
```

and all three forms have the same class so it automatically takes the last form and runs the function. How do I make it so that it takes the form who's button I clicked and alerts the input-value of the clicked form WITHOUT changing the class or adding an ID to the form? Is there a way? I need all the forms to be the same (except for their input-value's).

Comment: Why not give unique `id` to each form?

Comment: @NikhilTalreja That wouldn't help, unless you want to create three identical click handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your click event handler is given a reference to the button that was clicked as the `this` context for the callback function. Use that to select the correct form:

```
$('.voteForm').click( function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).closest('form').serialize());
});
```

Better yet, rearchitect your markup so you have a single form, or *no form at all*, and just use the value of the thing which is being clicked. Using three forms for this which all submit to the same URL is a little odd.

Comment: @maegar Perfect, thanks. I'm creating a web-application using a framework (an app where users can make posts and like each others posts) and when a user visits myWebsite.com/home/, all of the users posts can be viewed. Each post comes with a 'like' button which, if clicked, 1 like is added to the number of total likes for that post. That's why the buttons all submit to the same URL. Because the URL they submit to deals with /handles the number of likes of the post. I removed lots of code and only posted the required code (the Jquery / ajax part of it) because the other stuff isn't necessary.